# Gmail in Mail on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, mail.app, gmail, authentication

I have an old iPhone 5 with iOS 10. When trying to login to a Gmail account in the Settings app in order to use the Mail app I get this from Google:

> Error 403: disallowed_useragent
> You can’t sign in from this screen because this app doesn’t comply with Google’s secure browsers policy. If this app has a website, you can open a web browser and try signing in from there.

It basically means that Google has (correctly) classified the user agent as an embedded web view, which goes against their policy (reasonable, I think).

The question now is: can the **Mail** app on iOS 10 still be used with Gmail *somehow*?

I simply enjoy keeping devices alive and I enjoy using iOS Mail if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried signing in with an App Password?

1. Go to your Google Account > Manage your Google Account.
2. Select Security.
3. Under "Signing in to Google," select App Passwords.

From google support answer:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Hmm, interesting. No, I'll have to look into that!

Comment: Hello, @Nilesh. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.

Comment: How does using an App Password overcome a "disallowed_useragent" problem?

Comment: Last time I checked, those clients didn't support two factor authentication so you had to use an app password.